# Parse XML elements and write only selected attributes with values to yaml file

Tags: xml, yaml

I have a requirement of converting some attributes of XML file into yaml format and change the attributes to customized name while writing to yaml.
I am aware of dump function which will read a stream and dump whole content in yaml, but without customization. Does anyone have any better libraries which does to achieve the above?

Comment: Why did you edit out the code from your post, not it is just asking for a library, which is a reason to close this question. I also don't understand that you if you found a solution, then why are you looking for a better library that does the **same** thing? How would you notice that is better if it does the same? Is speed the issue? (You are using that word "same", I don't think it means what you think it means).

Comment: my requirement is to parse only few attributes from xml and write to yaml file whereas dump function does then entire xml loaded data to yaml format .Also have requirement of customising tag name from xml to different name in yaml format  ..  hence existing dump cannot be used so i was asking for any functions which can be used to achieve this

Comment: You should write that in your post, including code with what you tried, and the XML input (or a minimal version). And definitely stop using the word **same**, because that has nothing to do with being the same as what you did before.